# $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ st $f(\frac{1}{2^n})=0 \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ , show $f'(0)=f''(0)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let$f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be twice differentiable function such that $f(\frac{1}{2^n})=0 \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $f'(0)=f''(0)=0$
>
> Applying mean value theorem on $(\frac{1}{2^n},\frac{1}{2^{n-1}})$ we see that $\exists c_n$ st $f'(c_n)=\frac{f(\frac{1}{2^{n-1}})-f(\frac{1}{2^{n}})}{\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}-\frac{1}{2^{n}}}$ , thus $f'(c_n) =0$ $\implies$ $\lim_{n\to \infty}f'(c_n)=0 \implies f'(0)=0$

But I can't use similar argument for $f''$ since it is not known whether it is continuous or not!

Comment: $f$ is not defined at $0$, therefore $f'(0)$ and $f''(0)$ do not exist.

Comment: @Mercy ? Why isn't $\;f\;$ defined in zero? How do you know that? It is given it is a twice differentiable function...(on the whole of $\;\Bbb R\;$ , according to the given info), so why do you say it is not defined at zero?

Comment: @DonAntonio $f$ is defined from $(0,1)$ into $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes @Mercy, I can see there's a difference between the question's title and the question's body...

Comment: I'm sorry I've edited it now!

Comment: Note that for $f''$ to exist, $f'$ must be continuous

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: For any sequence $x_n \to 0$ with $x_n \neq 0$ for all $n$, you have

$$f''(0) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f'(x_n)-f'(0)}{x_n}.$$

Picking the right sequence yields the result quickly.

For example the sequence $(c_n)$ of zeros of $f'$, with $c_n \in \left(\frac{1}{2^n},\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right)$ whose existence was established in the question. Then each of the quotients is $0$, hence so is the limit.

Comment: okay so choosing $x_n= \frac{1}{2^n}$ will work, BTW you are replacing the usual $h$ in definition of derivative by sequence which is going to zero to re write the expression for derivative so is it obvious kind of thing or it requires a proof?

Comment: No, $x_n = \frac{1}{2^n}$ works for $f'(0)$, for $f''(0)$ you should take something else. By definition of the derivative, the derivative is the limit of the difference quotients for _all_ sequences converging to $0$, so we can just take any convenient sequence to determine the limit.

Comment: oops I see $x_n =\frac{1}{2^n}$ will work for $f'(0)$

Comment: which sequence will work for $f''(0)$?

Comment: One with $f'(x_n) = 0$ would be nice.

Comment: how do we know $\exists$ such a sequence?

Comment: You have such a sequence in your question. It is called $c_n$ there.

Comment: oh I see! I was thinking of some example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14623/discussion-between-neeraj-bhauryal-and-daniel-fischer).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative argument is to write down the second-order Taylor polynomial $P$ of $f$ at $0$ (which, given the hypotheses, we know exists). It has the property that

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-P(x)}{x^2}=0. \tag{$\star$}$$

(Set $P(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac12 f''(0)x^2$ and use ($\star$) when we set $x=2^{-n}$ to show $f'(0)=f''(0)=0$.)